# python kivy, label, button

Tags: python, button, список, kivy, label

Помогите пожалуйста как сделать чтобы список выводился по очереди при нажатии конпки ' Правда или действие '

```
    def ActionOrTruth(self, instance):
        players = [ self.name_one.text,
                    self.name_two.text,
                    self.name_three.text,
                    self.name_four.text ]
            
        self.label = Label(text = str(players), pos = (305, 325))
        self.add_widget(self.label)

        play = ['Правда', 'Действие']
        start = random.choice(play)

        instance.text = start
```

Answer (score 1):

вот мой код, думаю тут наглядно показано.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

from collections import deque # главное

text_scrolls = []
q = deque()
q.append('Когда был первый поцелй?')
q.append('Что тебе нравится ?')
q.append('Ты голоден ?')

e = deque()
e.append('Бегай')
e.append('Поцелуй руку')
e.append('Играй роль босса ')

Builder.load_string("""
<Gex>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Button:
    text: 'Правда'
    on_press: root.upd()

  Button:
    text: 'Действие'
    on_press: root.upd_1()

  Label:
    id: fer
    text:"..."

""")
class Gex(BoxLayout):

  def upd(self):
    self.ids['fer'].text = str(q.popleft())

  def upd_1(self):
    self.ids['fer'].text = str(e.popleft())

class FakeApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Gex()

FakeApp().run()
```

Comment: а как можно сделать что бы это еще и повтрялось тоесть когда доходит до последнего вопроса начиналось все сначало ?

Comment: это я не знаю как сделать, попробуйте сделать очень огромный список или включите random.

Comment: Все равно, спасибо вам)

Answer (score 0):

Вот на основе алгоритма!

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout

numbering_1 = -1
numbering_2 = -1
limit_1 = 0
limit_2 = 0


text_scrolls_1 = ['Когда был первый поцелй?','Что тебе нравится ?',
'Ты голоден ?',"ggggg","wwwww",'rrrr']

text_scrolls_2 = ["trt","ttrtrxxx","trtrtds","tfdfdffd"]

Builder.load_string("""
<Gex>:
  orientation: 'vertical'
  Button:
    text: 'Правда'
    on_press: root.upd()

  Button:
    text: 'Действие'
    on_press: root.upd_1()

  Label:
    id: fer
    text:"..."

""")
class Gex(BoxLayout):
  def upd(self):
    global numbering_1
    limit_1 = len(text_scrolls_1)
    if numbering_1 < limit_1 -1:
      numbering_1 += 1
      self.ids['fer'].text = str(text_scrolls_1[numbering_1])
    else:
      numbering_1= 0
      self.ids['fer'].text = str(text_scrolls_1[numbering_1])

  def upd_1(self):
    global numbering_2
    limit_2 = len(text_scrolls_2)
    if numbering_2 < limit_2 -1:
      numbering_2 += 1
      self.ids['fer'].text = str(text_scrolls_2[numbering_2])
    else:
      numbering_2 = 0
      self.ids['fer'].text = str(text_scrolls_2[numbering_2])

class FakeApp(App):
  def build(self):
    return Gex()


FakeApp().run()
```